# Apple wireless keyboard won't work after cleaning it

Tags: mac, wireless-keyboard

I have an old Apple wireless keyboard Vintage 2007. I pulled off all the keys to give it a thorough cleaning with a dampened cloth.

I replaced all the keys and my iMac recognizes the keyboard but none of the keys work and even the light for caps lock doesn't light up.

Any suggestions? Before you ask, it is turned on and has new batteries.

Comment: Is it shown as connected in the Bluetooth preference pane?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these steps will help :

1. BT Keyboard should be turned off
2. Click on the Bluetooth icon in the toolbar and you’ll see “Set Up Bluetooth Device”, click that
3. The Bluetooth Set Up Assistance window will come up and start searching
   HERE’S THE TRICK
4. Turn on the BT Keyboard by pushing the button on the side, BUT HOLD THE BUTTON IN. DO NOT LET IT GO! You have to hold the button in for the ENTIRE PROCESS.
5. The Set Up Assistance will find your keyboard.
6. Click on the Name of the Keyboard and click on CONTINUE
   AGAIN, YOU HAVE TO BE HOLDING THE POWER BUTTON ON THE KEYBOARD DOWN THIS ENTIRE TIME
7. You will get the Pairing Code. Type that on the keyboard.
8. YOU’RE KEYBOARD SHOULD BE PAIRED NOW!